# Sorting List Items in European Currency Format

Tags: jquery, sorting, locale, currency

I'm currently making a page with loads of products on, which need to be sorted by name, popularity and price.

I'm using the tinySort plugin, which has worked perfectly on locales that use a decimal point in their currency, but it's not working so well in European locales that format their price as '12,95 €'

Basically, I need a function that converts the price attribute into a number which is sortable.

Each box uses the following code

```
<li class="box" id="234860200" >
    <img src="#" alt="" class="packshot" title="">
    <p class="productTitle"></p>
    <div class="bottomAlign">
    <p><span class="price"></span> <span class="strikethrough strikeOFF"></span></p>

    <input id="" type="checkbox" name="product" data-price="" class="calculation-item" value=""/>
<label for="" class="calculation-label"><span class="checkboxTitle"></span><span class="defaultAdd">Add to Basket</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>                     
</li>
```

The sorting button uses the following js

```
function priceLow() {
    $('ul#productList>li').tsort('span.price');
}
```

If anyone could help me, that would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
function priceLow() {
    $('ul#productList>li').tsort('span.price',
      {
         sortFunction: function(a,b) {
           var a_val = parseFloat(a.s.replace(/,/, "."));
           var b_val = parseFloat(b.s.replace(/,/, "."));

           return (a_val==b_val) ? 0 : ((a_val>b_val) ? 1 : -1);
         }
      }
    );
}
```